# Jupyter notebook dataframes deleted

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, shared-libraries, geopandas

As I believe I'm facing the weirdest problem ever. I'm running my python script in jupyter notebook, mostly using geopandas, and at a certain point, without an error popping up, all my dataframes (or geodataframes) are lost. Not only the one I'm currently working on at that point of the script, but all the previously generated ones also. I've googled the problem but the only proposed solution is to update my libraries, which doesn't solve the problem. The script is running fine on other PC's. Any ideas would be more than appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify a little more? Are you just working through the notebook from top to bottom? Are you closing and reopening? Do they visually disappear, or are the actual dataframes being lost in memory (i.e. `NameError` if you try to reference them)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just working from top to bottom. The variables get emptied and the dataframes are lost from the memory after the breaking, but no error message pops up. This happens when trying to create natural breaks from the jenkspy library at some of the dataframe's columns.